# CP852 encoding in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, character-encoding

I need to connect to pqsql db and read data encoded in CP852 (MSDos latin2). How can I achive that goal? All other database systems (oracle, mysql, sqlserver) support it. According to documentation it is not supported. Are there easier ways than source manipulation?

I have legacy application that connects with cp852 to mysql cp1250. I want to swap db for pgsql.

So I have data in cp1250 and I need to read it in cp852. Can't change data or application.

Answer (score 1):

If there are no other applications that use the database, you could use a PostgreSQL database with encoding `sql_ascii` and store your data in code page 852. With this encoding, PostgreSQL doesn't care about encoding.

If there are other applications that use the database and work with different encodings, the only solution would be to change your legacy application to either use a different encoding or to first convert the data correctly (it shouldn't be too hard write the conversion from `WIN1250` to code page 852 yourself.

Comment: There are other applications that need data in win1250. Generally there is just one application that needs data in cp852. I would be happy even with something like db proxy that would convert 1250 outputted by db to 852 for my application on the fly.